# Undefined method `user_id=' for #<Comment

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I trying to create app, with 3 model user, posts and comment.They 3 models 
associated "has_many" and "belongs_to" associations.But I did not get do that would have been comments from the user, how to do it?

controller comments_controller.Here browser show an error in 5 line (Undefined method `user_id=' for #

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @comment = @post.comments.create(comment_params)
    @comment.user_id = current_user.id
    redirect_to post_path(@post)
  end

  private
    def comment_params
      params.require(:comment).permit(:body)
    end
end
```

model comment.rb

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
  belongs_to :user
end
```

model user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :posts
has_many :comments
end
```

model post.rb

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :comments
end
```

shema.rb

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20141114150704) do

  create_table "comments", force: true do |t|
    t.text     "body"
    t.integer  "post_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  add_index "comments", ["post_id"], name: "index_comments_on_post_id"

  create_table "posts", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.text     "text"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "users", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "email"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "password_digest"
    t.string   "remember_token"
  end

  add_index "users", ["remember_token"], name: "index_users_on_remember_token"

end
```

**UPD**
full error trace

```
app/controllers/comments_controller.rb:5:in `create'
actionpack (4.1.6) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
actionpack (4.1.6) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:189:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.1.6) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.1.6) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.1.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:113:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:113:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.1.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.1.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.1.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.1.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.1.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:86:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:86:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.1.6) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.1.6) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.1.6) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.1.6) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.1.6) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (4.1.6) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
actionpack (4.1.6) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.1.6) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
activerecord (4.1.6) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.1.6) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in `process'
actionview (4.1.6) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
actionpack (4.1.6) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:196:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.1.6) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.1.6) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:232:in `block in action'
actionpack (4.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:82:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:82:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:50:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:73:in `block in call'
actionpack (4.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `each'
actionpack (4.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:678:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:35:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/head.rb:11:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:254:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
activerecord (4.1.6) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
activerecord (4.1.6) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:621:in `call'
activerecord (4.1.6) lib/active_record/migration.rb:380:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.1.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:82:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
railties (4.1.6) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (4.1.6) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.1.6) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (4.1.6) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
activesupport (4.1.6) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
railties (4.1.6) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.6) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:26:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
railties (4.1.6) lib/rails/engine.rb:514:in `call'
railties (4.1.6) lib/rails/application.rb:144:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
/home/weare138/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
/home/weare138/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
/home/weare138/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
```

sorry for my bad English

Comment: Depending on your Rails version, you might need to add attr_accessible :user_id to your Comment model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have `user_id` in your migration. To solve this you can follow either of these:

#### Solution 1:

Create a new migration:

```
$ rails g migration AddUseIdToComments user_id:integer
```

open `AddUseIdToComments` migration file to see if it has:

```
add_column :comments, :user_id, :integer
```

then run:

```
$ rake db:migrate
```

#### Solution 2:

Instead of:

```
create_table "comments", force: true do |t|
  t.text     "body"
  t.integer  "post_id"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
end
```

Change it to:

```
create_table "comments", force: true do |t|
  t.text     "body"
  t.integer  "post_id"
  t.integer  "user_id"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
end
```

Run:

```
$ rake db:rollback # to rollback old migration 
$ rake db:migrate # re run it
```

I'd encourage you create a new migration like mentioned in Solution 1, as in future if you keep   a habit of editing existing migration then you may end up with undesirable issues.

Once you're done making migration change. You'll need to change `create` method in your `CommentsController` to this:

```
def create
  @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
  @comment = @post.comments.create(comment_params)
  @comment.user_id = current_user.id
  if @comment.save
    redirect_to post_path(@post)
  else
    render :new
  end
end
```

You're not saving your `@comment` object. Note line `@comment.save`, it saves and returns true or false based on the transaction's status(successful/ failed) and redirects to posts path or render `new` method.

***Update***: from your error trace it seems like you don't have `current_user` defined.

See line:

```
@comment.user_id = current_user.id
```

if `current_user` is nil then you'll get undefined method `id` for nil class. You need to make sure that `current_user` helper returns appropriate user instance instead of nil. If you're using any authentication library like devise, then it means you're trying to access `current_user` when your user isn't logged in, i.e. session isn't yet been made. Make sure you login before doing this operation.

Comment: Thank you, I see.But when comment created show an error "undefined method `id' for nil".

Comment: @vveare138 : This seems like a different issue. What's the error trace?

Comment: but user was authenticate http://tinypic.com/r/e88ilt/8. Cookies working, and it means that the user log in, is not it?

Comment: @vveare138 : No, `current_user` isn't set properly. You need to see what's wrong with it, either session isn't being written properly or user isn't logged in.

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no user_id in your Comments table execute the following commands from the terminal in your rails application folder to add it

```
rails generate migration AddUseridToComments user_id:integer
```

which will add a colum containing user_id to your table Comments

and then execute

```
rake db:migrate
```

to add the column to your production or development database

After that the application should be able to find user_id